# Springer Materials database molecule visualizer's 'crooked' straight-chain alkanes — science or art?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

The [Springer Materials](http://materials.springer.com/) database includes a molecule visualizer tool:

> Enhanced data visualization features display interactive crystal structures, data tables, and phase diagrams with export options for further analysis.

I noticed that some of the straight-chain alkanes $\ce{ C_nH_{2n+2} }$ appear to be clearly curved, other's look more like random displacements, while others nearly straight. I'm wondering if this is:

1. Just some random noise "as a helpful reminder" to the viewer that these are quantum systems with vibrations
2. "...helpful reminder" that long chain molecules bend and wiggle depending on temperature
3. Representation the static shape of the molecules
4. Something else?

Does octadecane really "look like" a human spine?

[image]

[image] [image] [image]

**above:** GIF is made from python-processed screenshots of n-octane through n-octadecane from [Springer Materials](http://materials.springer.com/) molecule visualizer. Still are the last three in the series. Most have slight atomic displacements that appear at first to be random, but the last one available $\ce{ C_{18}H_{38} }$ suddenly looks like my spine when I've been slouching over StackExchange all day instead of getting work done. Why?

Comment: I guess this is just some random noise, not even quantum in nature.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I wonder if the randomness was added *as a reminder* of either the quantum nature of molecules, or their flexibility. I"m not asking here about the mechanism (which is really interesting but haven't done any research yet), just the intent of the algorithm that springer is using.

Comment: Their intent is a mystery, but my bet is on flexibility.

Comment: Yes a mystery. If you want a better idea you could (a) do a full MD simulation or (b) more simply simulate what is happening by performing random walks on a tetrahedral lattice and limit close approach to simulate van-der-waals atom sizes.